# Rails: Ask for register after submit content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails App, I made a `form_for` to allow any visitor to submit their content.
But after submit, I want to ask user, whether they want to register for this site or not.

There are some approach to this:

1. Redirect after user submits the form, left the initial post **anonymous**.
2. Much the same as the first one. But **somehow** help user to **reclaim** the post they just make
3. Store the content in **some place** first and do not submit. Instead, ask for register. And after register, show the **stored content before** and ask user to submit again.

Basically, I can implement the 1st method. But it seems just not that good. For the 2nd and 3rd one, I do not know how to **reclaim** the post or **store content beforehand**.

Is there a standard way to do this? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For solving the same kind of problem, I chose your 3rd option. For that you can use sessions, it  will allow you to keep some information in memory related to a specific connection to your server.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways.

First of all you need to keep in mind that these are different behaviors from which you should chose first and do not let the implementation force you to chose one.

For the second case you can have the `id` of the post that was created (along with some guarantees that it is an orphan post) and then tweak your register method to also assign a post to a user after creating one.

The Third case can be implemented by storing the post data either to session or to a backend temporary store and retrieve them if needed.